# How to check if a dataset exists in BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

We can initiate a BigQuery dataset as follows:

```
dataset_ref = self.client.dataset(dataset_id=self.dataset_id)
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
```

How can I check if this dataset exists already? When I look at the properties of dataset they seem to be overlapping for sets that exists and one that do not exist.

Comment: Try `if dataset.created` or `if dataset.created is not None`
https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.Dataset.html#google.cloud.bigquery.dataset.Dataset.created

Comment: There is a delay with that option. Basically it takes up to a couple of seconds, if not minutes for that value to be filled.

Comment: Can you try and create the dataset and catch the exception if it already exists?

Comment: Yes I can catch it with the exception `Conflict` (from `google.api_core.exceptions import Conflict`), but I was hoping on a more elegant solution. Also when you dig into `google.cloud.bigquery.dataset` I don't see any helpful methods.

Comment: else `dataset._properties.get("creationTime")` might save you a few milliseconds.

Comment: ```if dataset  in set(k.dataset_id for k in bigquery.Client().list_datasets())``` ??

Comment: You can also use `bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)` inside a try catch block. So, if exists you append the result. Otherwise, you create it, both specifying the `writeDisposition` as desired, [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.html).  Would this be feasible for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the error using exists_ok parameter in create_dataset function.

```
# create dataset if not exists

self.client.create_dataset(dataset_id=self.dataset_id, exists_ok=True)
```

I have found it in Google's bigquery API [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/4a3ab033357fcb4fcf4971edabf464129dff7329/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L572).

Answer (score 7):

The [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/datasets.html) recommend using `get_dataset` to determine if a dataset exists.

```
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound

dataset_id = "pigs_in_space"

try:
    client.get_dataset(dataset_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Dataset {} already exists".format(dataset_id))
except NotFound:
    print("Dataset {} is not found".format(dataset_id))
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is that it will log an error each time you make this call.